# Is there something like python's issubclass which will return False if the first arg is not a Class?

Tags: python

I'd like `issubclass(1, str)` to return false, `1` is not a subclass of `str`. Because it's not a class at all I get a TypeError.

Is there a good way to test this without resorting to a `try, except`?

```
try:
    if issubclass(value, MyClass):
        do_stuff()
except TypeError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import inspect
def isclassandsubclass(value, classinfo):
    return inspect.isclass(value) and issubclass(value, classinfo)
```

Answer (score 4):

You seem to want isinstance:

```
>>> isinstance(1, str)
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Without importing any module:

```py
def issubclass_(c, clazz):
    return isinstance(c, type) and issubclass(c, clazz)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your usecase is but checking against a class or an instance of a class are too completely different things (and have different API methods: issubclass() vs. isinstance()).

So you always have to check if your 'item' is an instance of something of a class.

>

```
>> (1).__class__
<type 'int'>
>>> (1).__class__.__class__
<type 'type'>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could simply check before calling `issubclass()`:

```
import types

def myissubclass (c, sc):
    if type(c) != types.ClassType
        return False
    return issubclass (c, sc)
```

but I think it would be more pythonic to embrace exceptions:

```
def myissubclass (c, sc):
    try:
        return issubclass (c, sc)
    except TypeError:
        return False
```