# issubclass raises exception if first argument is not a class

Tags: python

I am developing a Python application where i need many times to check if an object is a subclass of a DB model.

I did my own function to do that:

```
def isModel(obj):
    return isinstance(obj, type) and issubclass(obj, Model)
```

`issubclass` raises exception of obj is not a class, but i would like it just return False if `obj` is not a class.

I thought better to make another function, to use instead of the built-in `issubclass`:

```
def _issubclass(obj, Klass):
    return isinstance(obj, type) and issubclass(obj, Klass)
```

But why the built-in `issubclass` was not made like that? What's the reason? Am i missing something?

---

**UPDATE:**

I have models:

```
class BaseModel(object):
    id = Field(...)

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    deleted = Field(...)
```

In a function i want check if an argument is a `BaseModel`:

```
def update_model(model):
    assert isinstance(model, type) and issubclass(model, BaseModel), 'Must be a model'
```

`issubclass` answers the question if an object is a sub-class of the given class. If the object is a class instance, so the answer, IMO, should be 'No, your object is not a BaseModel subclass, because it's not a class at all'.

In Python is quite normal instead of `if something is not None or len(something) != 0` to use `if something` and not raising any `TypeError`. What's the usefulness of raising TypeError if the first argument of `issubclass` is not a class?

For example someone asks a dog: 'Are you the right man to solve this task?', and instead of answering 'No', the dog says 'I am not a man'. I asked someone one thing (is sub class) and he didn't answer my question.

Comment: raising a `TypeError` seems to me the perfectly natural thing to do... it encourages doing things properly. You're trying to give `issubclass` bad data; just like `float('foo')` will raise a ValueError rather than returning `float('nan')` as it would in some languages, it's just the Python way of doing things. If you were working in a staticly typed language it would generally choke at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isinstance will probably do what you want. `isinstance(obj, Klass)` will return True when obj is an instance of a class that is a subclass of Klass.
Example:

```
>>> class A(object):
...    pass
... 
>>> class B(A):
...    pass
... 
>>> obj = B()
>>> 
>>> isinstance(obj, A)
True
```

"What's the usefulness of raising TypeError if the first argument of issubclass is not a class?"

Explicit is better than implicit. You passed a non-class into issubclass. That indicates that you are doing something wrong. Therefore you get an error. If you seriously do want to pass instances to issubclass, you can catch that error:

```
try:
    isbasemodel = False
    if issubclass(x, BaseModel):
       isbasemodel = True
except TypeError:
    # Accept that we test non-classes:
    pass
```

Or, of course, you can do what you do: An extra check.

However, if it did *not* raise an error, then it would be impossible to catch the mistake of passing in an instance.

From what I understand, you want to make a check in an API or similar, that the object passed in is a subclass of BaseModel, and the user should not be allowed to pass in an instance. IMO, the correct thing to do there is to raise a TypeError if they pass in the wrong thing. Like so:

```
def update_model(model):
    if not issubclass(model, BaseModel):
        raise TypeError('Must be a model')
```

Making an assert there just means that you hide the fact that it is a type error to pass in the wrong thing.

Comment: sorry, it's not what i asked. my code is working as in the question. just wondering why `issubclass` raises exception when its first argument is a class instance, forcing me to do additional check `isinstance(obj, type)`

Comment: I don't think that's what he's trying to achieve; I think he's only wanting to change the behaviour so that instead of raising a TypeError it returns False. If that's it, @warvariuc, I'd recommend that you *don't* do this as it encourages sloppy coding. You should *know* if you're dealing with the class or an instance, unless you can provide a good reason why not.

Comment: @warvariuc: Well, I think I answered that question. :-) isinstance is for instances, issubclass is for classes. I updated my answer with an answer to your "why" question.

Comment: `instances are not classes` strictly speaking, in python, classes are instance of metaclasses (which is just a regular class).

Comment: right. Classes are instances, but instances are not always classes.

Comment: > Making an assert there just means that you hide the fact that it is a type error to pass in the wrong thing. < That is my question. I don't really care about the TypeError - i just must be sure that the argument is a needed class. Either it's a class instance or a wrong class - in both cases it's an error - equally important. That's why i said > `issubclass` answers the question if an object is a sub-class of the given class.'

Comment: For example someone asks a dog: 'Are you the right man to solve this task?', and instead of answering 'No', the dog says 'I am not a man'. I asked someone one thing (is sub class) and he didn't answer my question.

Comment: In Python is quite normal instead of `if something is not None or len(something) != 0` to use `if something`  and not raising any TypeError. That's why i asked > What's the usefulness of raising TypeError if the first argument of issubclass is not a class? <

Comment: @warvariuc: Since you want to make sure that the argument is a needed class, using issubclass will result in exactly what you want: The raising of an exception if it is not a subclass. You also will get different exceptions if you pass in a non-class as if you pass in the wrong class, which is beneficial. He *did* answer your question. "You you the right man" - "I am not a man". That is the correct answer, telling you that the question is the wrong one.

Comment: @warvariuc: The usefulness is exactly the same. Being None and having length zero is different things. Not being a subclass and not being a class are different things. They should give different errors, for reasons explained in my answer. I'm unsure of what is unclear and what you are asking now.

Answer (score 1):

I found a more elegant way using metaclasses (as my models use them anyway):

```
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2

>>> class ModelMeta(type):
...     "Metaclass for models"
... 
>>> class Model(object):
...     "DB model"
...     __metaclass__ = ModelMeta
... 
>>> class MyModel(Model):
...     "A real model"
... 
>>> isinstance(MyModel, type) and issubclass(MyModel, Model)
True
>>> myModelInstance = Model()
>>> issubclass(MyModel, Model)
True
>>> issubclass(myModelInstance, Model)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
>>> isinstance(MyModel, type) and issubclass(MyModel, Model)
True
>>> isinstance(myModelInstance, type) and issubclass(myModelInstance, Model)
False
>>> isinstance(MyModel, ModelMeta)
True
>>> isinstance(myModelInstance, ModelMeta)
False
>>>
```

So, `isinstance(MyModel, ModelMeta)` is what i use now.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the docs for [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance) and [`issubclass`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#issubclass). They explain everything.

You do mean "an object is a subclass of a DB model", right? That it will be a class, not a class instance? Then isn't that exactly what issubclass does? Why the fiddling around with isinstance? – Chris Morgan just now edit

Comment: > You do mean "an object is a subclass of a DB model", right? < AFAIK, classes are also objects. `obj` maybe anything - a class or class instance.

Comment: a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658576/is-there-something-like-pythons-issubclass-which-will-return-false-if-the-first

Comment: Yes. But what you were saying was not at all clear. It still isn't, if that's not what you meant (though I *think* I get what you're trying to ask). Could you please update your question to be crystal clear about what you're wanting to achieve?